# Limit a php function to one result

Tags: php, for-loop

How would I limit this query so it only gives me one result?

Code:

```
function next_prodn_header() {

    $StartDate = get('start_date');
    $timestamp = strtotime($StartDate);

    $EndDate = get('end_date');
    $Now = strtotime(date('d-m-Y'));
    $Start = strtotime($EndDate); 
    $newStart = date_i18n('d-m-Y', $Start);

    if ($Now <= $Start) {

 for ($i = 1; $i < 1; $i++) {
     echo "<h2>Next Event</h2>";
     echo "<span class=\"month\">";
     echo date_i18n('M', $timestamp);
     echo "</span>\n";
     echo "<span class=\"year\">";
     echo date_i18n('Y', $timestamp);
     echo "</span>\n\t\t";
     echo "<p><a href='";
     echo the_permalink();
     echo "' title='";
     echo the_title();
     echo "'>";
     echo the_title();
     echo "</a></p>\n\t\t";
     }
    } else {
  echo "";
    }
}
```

Comment: What query? You're either using the wrong term or we're missing some code. There is no query in the snippet you gave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by *query* you meant your `for` loop, start the loop at `$i = 0`. As of right now, your for-loop structure checks if `1 < 1` which evaluates to false, so it doesn't run the code inside of the loop.

Otherwise, I am not exactly sure what your question is regarding.

Comment: ... or just remove the loop entirely.